# Rally API to retrieve corresponding test sets & test cases by applying query filter with Project ID & Iteration name?

Tags: java, rest, api, rally

I tried the below API but not able to filter the results with the ProjectID.The response test sets under iteration Sprint:18.2 irrespective of the project.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset?query=(Iteration.name = "Sprint:18.2")&query=(ProjectID= "177771658096")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this particular query one of two ways.  The first, update your query to be:

```
?query=((Project.ObjectID = "177771658096") AND (Iteration.Name = "Sprint:18.2"))
```

and the second, add the Project in this way:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset?project=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/177771658096&query=(Iteration.name = "Sprint:18.2")
```

Comment: The second option worked for me,thanks....